# Optimize SQL statement with too many connections

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I wrote the code below but it is too network consuming because content.mDName.Count is above 30k. Could anyone help me with alternatives on how to optimize it in order to reduce the amount of iterations?

```
    public List<int> GetMDIB([FromBody] MD content)
    {

        var values = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < content.mDName.Count; i++)
        {
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(BasicAuthHttpModule.connectionString))
            using (var cmdgetall = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmdgetall.CommandText = "SELECT tbmd.mdID FROM tbmd WHERE tbmd.mdDFID = " + content.dFID[i] + " AND tbmd.mdName = '" + content.mDN[i] + "';";
                using (var reader = cmdgetall.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                        values.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("mdID")));
                    else
                        values.Add(-1);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
```

TRIAL 1 (Not Working):

```
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(BasicAuthHttpModule.connectionString))
        using (var cmdgetall = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            whr = "SELECT IFNULL(tbmd.mdID,-1) FROM tbmd WHERE ";


            for (int i = 0; i < content.mDN.Count; i++)
            {

                whr = whr + "(tbmd.mdDFID = " + content.dFID[i] + " AND tbmd.mdName = '" + content.mDN[i] + "') ";

                if (i < content.mDName.Count - 1)
                    whr = whr + "OR ";
                else
                    whr = whr + ";";
            }

            cmdgetall.CommandText = whr;


            using (var reader = cmdgetall.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("mdID")));
                }
                else
                    values.Add(-1);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: How many rows are there in `mdID`? Maybe do `select *` and go through the resultset manually. Maybe query 50 entries of content at the same time in one query. You could add them to a temporary table (in packs of 50 or 100) and then use a `join` to retrieve the result. Where does `content` come from? If you got it from the database, you could query these values already there.

Comment: I would have the for loop on the inside of the first 2 shown usings

Comment: "mdID" always has one row. "content" is an object from C# application.

Comment: how long is it taking before and after ? 30k select stmts?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work, because I need each result not found by Select to return -1.

Comment: You want to get 30k items, but how many possible elements are there in the DB?

Comment: @Gabriel: I meant: how many rows are there in total in the table mdID. If there are e.g. 100k rows, you could get them all at once and analyze them manually. And `content`: I know it's a c# object, but you got the data in it somewhere (you hopefully didn't manually enter 30k values). If you e.g. loaded them earlier into your app from a (or the same) database, you maybe could just get the values you need here already when you load the original data into content.

Comment: Your trial 1 will not work because a) the query is too long (you may have to split it in batches of some 50 or 100 entries) and b) you have to do a post-analysis: you have to go through content and check if you have an entry for that in the resultset (if not: add -1, otherwise add the result). The fastest way to do it is if you sort `content` (or a copy of it) first (and before the first query), and use an `order by` in your query.

Comment: Or you could use `ado.net`/`datatable` to load your table (maybe even into memory). It will do most of the internal work and optimization (loading everything, caching, ...) for you, and you can just do lookups.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare, I accomplished it using your idea. Split in batches and doing a post-analysis.